# Printing date from Year, Month and Day columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to add a new column - "date" to my Pandas dataframe. Below are the first 5 rows of my dataframe:
[First 5 rows of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN0as.png)
As seen from the image, the first column is year, second month, and third day. Below is what I have tried to do:

```
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year','Month','Day']])
```

But, I keep getting the error as below:

```
ValueError: cannot assemble the datetimes: time data '610101' does not match format 
'%Y%m%d' (match)
```

It would be great if I can get any help for the same.

Comment: I guess 61 is not recognize as a year. the format %Y%m%d is usually 1961010. So I suggest you add 1900 to your year column

Comment: you have NaNs in your rows somewhere which is coercing the integeral values to float. This is resulting in coercion errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment, I was able to reproduce the error and solve it by adding 1900 to the year

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [61,99], "month": [1, 2], "day": [3, 12]})
df["year"] = df["year"] + 1900
df['full_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']])
```

Output:

```
    year    month   day full_date
0   1961    1   3   1961-01-03
1   1999    2   12  1999-02-12
```

There is a `format` parameter to the `to_datetime` method but for some reason I wasn't able to make it work. [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```py
df['full_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']], format="%y%m%d", infer_datetime_format=False)
```

this still throw the same error although I am using `%y` which should be 2 digit year but the error message still says it does not match this format `'%Y%m%d'`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df.apply(lambda x:'%s %s %s' % (x['year'],x['month'], x['day']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about printing out what is actually showing for your selection first ?

```
print(df[['Year','Month','Day']])
```

if the data is indeed "610101", then you would likely need to modify it with '19':

```
pd.to_datetime('19' + df[['Year','Month','Day']])
```